# Not getting data after XML Parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using XML parser to get my data.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"country"] ) 
    {
        x++;
       [messages addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:Id,@"ID",Name,@"NAME",Image,@"IMAGE",nil]];
    //**111**
         NSLog(@"Data in Message : %@", [messages objectAtIndex:(x-1)]);

        [Id setString:@""];
        [Name setString:@""];
        [Image setString:@""];
    }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"id"] )
    {
        [Id appendString:currentNodeContent];
    }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"name"] ) 
    {
        [Name appendString:currentNodeContent];
    }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"im"] ) 
    {
        [Image appendString:currentNodeContent];
    }
}
```

//At //****111**** the message is printed but when I do this after calling the xml parser, it doesn't print:

```
chatParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
[chatParser setDelegate:self];
[chatParser parse];

 NSLog(@"\n\nMessages...\n\n%@", messages); //here there is no data printing
```

at this point it is printing empty..

Messages.

```
(
        {
        ID = "";
        IMAGE = "";
        NAME = "";
    },
        {
        ID = "";
        IMAGE = "";
        NAME = "";
    },
        {
        ID = "";
        IMAGE = "";
        NAME = "";
    },
        {
        ID = "";
        IMAGE = "";
        NAME = "";
    },
        {
        ID = "";
        IMAGE = "";
        NAME = "";
    },

)
```

I have define message properties and also sythesize it.
In **viewDidLoad** I have did this

```
 messages=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Thank you for help..

Comment: Mushtag change your comparison of  string is not "id" is "ID"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you use same objects `Id, Name, Image` all the time and with the lines

```
[Id setString:@""];
[Name setString:@""];
[Image setString:@""];
```

set their values to "" at the end of each country element.

It better should look like this (not tested, maybe some typos):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
  currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"id"] )
  {
    [lastMessage setObject:currentNodeContent forKey:"ID"];
  }
  else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"name"] ) 
  {
    [lastMessage setObject:currentNodeContent forKey:"NAME"];
  }
  else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"im"] ) 
  {
    [lastMessage setObject:currentNodeContent forKey:"IMAGE"];
  }
  else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"country"] ) 
  {
    NSLog(@"Data in Message : %@", lastObject);
    [messages addObject:lastMessage];
    [lastMessage release];
  }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elName namespaceURI:(NSString *)uri 
{
   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"country"] )
   {
     lastMessage = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below Code.Where Table is NSObject Class with the CaseId,PartyId,CartId as a properties in this class.If you have the xml url just called loadXMLByURL method with URl.After parsing you will get Each Object in TableArray which have the Table object with above properties.

```
NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
NSXMLParser     *parser;
Tweet           *currentTweet;
bool            isStatus;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _tweets         = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

    - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"Table"]) 
        {
            currentTable = [Table alloc];
                isStatus = YES;
        }
    }

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (isStatus) 
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"CaseId"]) 
        {
            currentTable.CaseId = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"PartyId"]) 
        {
            currentTable.PartyId = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"CartId"]) 
        {
            currentTable.CartId = currentNodeContent;
        }

    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"Table"]) 
    {
        [self.tableArray addObject:currentTable];
        currentTable = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.